# position fixed not follow the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, position

I would build a web page with a main menu always on screen such this
[image]

There aren't any problems with resolution of screen more then 1300px such we can view  above image .

When I try to resize the broswer In order to change the resolution of a device the nav bar not follow the broswer resolution as we can view in the image below

[image]

This is the code of my page:

```
<style>
    .container{
        background-color: red;
        max-width: 1300px;
        /*allienamento div principale a centro*/
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5500px;
    }
    .logo{
        background-color: #00387C;
        width:220px;
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: fixed;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    nav.mainmenu{
        width: 100%;
        height: 160px;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background-color: #ffedb3;
        border-bottom-color: silver;
        border-bottom-style: ridge;
        border-bottom-width: thin;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
        padding-right: 1px;
        margin-right: 1px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <nav class="mainmenu">

    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what the problem is, it's not really clear from those pictures - they look the same except one is zoomed in with no white space

Comment: @Pete +1
Don't really understand what you're trying to get here

Comment: I added an indicator in the second image. 
I would the nav bar follow the red box size

Comment: What do you mean by "follow the red box"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply css rules

```
html{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
body{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `left: 0` to your `nav.mainmenu`.

Comment: No left:0 move the nav bar at the beginning of page